# Why `sudo nixos-rebuild` doesnt show output of trace?

Tags: nix

I expect this [here](https://github.com/srghma/dotfiles/commit/4bebd218956fe51c894704024be8685820d312fe#diff-71a9adeed47cb094fd6acd25d4edd10fR5)

```
let config_ = lib.debug.showVal (config); in
....
systemd     = import ./systemd     { inherit pkgs; config = config_; };
```

to show the content of config, why I don't see it?

```
$ sudo nixos-rebuild dry-build --show-trace
building the system configuration...
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/g24yj8lzz2zg921daibfbj2yz5933fwn-hubstaff-1.3.0-9b2ba62.drv
  /nix/store/hps81xprfk0b4lhq8z2vycn1jq4ds841-system-path.drv
  /nix/store/1s689dqbl45g094mnd5sjzdh44wrd6g5-dbus-1.drv
  /nix/store/wqhr5z2f7l0a49fxb4arkwagb1iwmkx4-unit-dbus.service.drv
  .....
  /nix/store/8r03578gxmk2plvxn4p0jbj8aal63vc6-lightdm.conf.drv
  /nix/store/i2ikmkxhgyns0ylj17cw2yv0v82m0lfh-etc.drv
  /nix/store/kwqbq4mmim8ph4i3zjbsi5hhwjr6qkg7-nixos-system-machine-18.03.131954.2569e482904.drv
```

Comment: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/38937

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That version of the `systemd/default.nix`](https://github.com/srghma/dotfiles/blob/4bebd218956fe51c894704024be8685820d312fe/nixos/root/systemd/default.nix#L45) function doesn't evaluate the `config` attribute of its argument, so it will not evaluate your debugging function either. The Nix language evaluates [by need](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nix_Expression_Language#Lazy).

To print `config`, make sure it gets evaluated. A function that may help you is `builtins.seq` it evaluates its first argument, but returns the second. Try this at the top of your file:

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

with pkgs;

builtins.seq (lib.debug.showVal config) {

  imports = [
    /* etcetera */
```